# Why does Haskell use arrows for the type of a function?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I just began learning Haskell and one of the strange things for me is the syntax for the type of a function with multiple arguments.

Consider a simple example:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Why we need all the arrows here? Wouldn’t it make more sense to write something like `Num Num Num -> Num`?

What is the reason under the hood? I searched for this question but couldn't find anything really helpful.

Comment: What would you write if you had `(Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first thing that is confusing things is the `Num a =>`, so we'll ignore that altogether for now. Instead, lets consider `Int -> Int -> Int`, which is one possible specialization of the type signature you gave.

Functions are almost always [curried](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying) in Haskell. This means that a multi-argument function is actually function of one argument that returns a function that takes the next argument, and so on.

The `->` is right associative, so `Int -> Int -> Int` is the same thing as `Int -> (Int -> Int)`.

This also means that this definition

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f x y = x + y
```

is the same as

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f x = \y -> x + y
```

In fact, all functions in Haskell take exactly one argument. Tuples exist as well, but they are first-class citizens so they are more than just an argument list.

The `Num a =>` is a bit of a different aspect of the type system. It says that the type variable `a` must be an instance of the `Num` type class. Common examples of types that are instances of `Num` include `Int` and `Double`. So `Num` isn't a type itself, it is a type class. `Num a =>` represents a constraint on the type variable `a`, it isn't another argument for the function.

The `(+)` method is a member of the `Num` type class, so you must constrain `a` in this way in order to use `(+)`. If you try to give `f` the signature `a -> a -> a` (with no constraint), it won't work because `a` is completely unconstrained and we know nothing about what types it can be. As a result, we couldn't use `(+)` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The type of each argument in the type signature of a function can contain whitespace, and so a non-whitespace separator is most likely required so the compiler (and humans!) can distinguish between them.

For example, you can have a parameterised abstract data type:

```
data MyType a = MyValue a
```

and a function that takes concrete types (constructed from the `MyType` type constructor):

```
myFunc :: MyType Int -> MyType Int -> String
```

If you didn't have the `->` between the arguments, the signature would look like

```
myFunc :: MyType Int MyType Int -> String   -- Not valid code
```

and a compiler would have much more trouble working out what the actual arguments of the function are meant to be (and I wonder if in some cases it might even be impossible?). At the very least, it's much less understandable.

Comment: I doubt you have understood the question. He is asking why haskell uses `A -> B -> C` instead of `A B -> C`. That is: what is on the left of the `->` is the argument list and what is on the right is the return type.

Comment: @Jeffrey You're right, I missed that. I've edited my answer slightly.